# Is celery-beats can only trigger a celery task or normal task (Django)?

Tags: django, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I am workign on a django project with celery and celery-beats. My main use case is use celery-beats to set up a periodical task as a background task, instead of using a front-end request to trigger. I would save the results and put it inside model, then pull the model to front-end view as a view to user.

My current problem is,  not matter how I change the way I am calling my task, it always throwing the task is not registered in the task list inside celery.

I am trying to trigger a non-celery task(inside, it will call a celery taskthe , using celery beats module,

Below is the pesudo-code.

tasks.py:

```
@app.shared_task
def longrunningtask(a):
   res = APIcall(a)
   return res
```

caller.py:

```
from .task import longrunningtask

def dosomething(input_list):
  for ele in input_list: 
     res.append(longrunningtask.delay(ele))
  return res
```

Periodical Task :

```
schedule, created = CrontabSchedule.objects.get_or_create(hour = 1, minute = 34)
task = PeriodicTask.objects.create(crontab=schedule, name="XXX_task_", task='app.caller.dosomething'))
return HttpResponse("Done")
```

Nothing special about the periodical task, but This never works for me. It errored that `not detected tasks or not registered tasks` if I do not make the dosomething() as celery task.

Problem is  I do not want to make the caller function a celery task, the reason being, that

1. Inside for loop, I would make parameter passing into the task(), I would like to see multiple celery long runing task is running with the for loop passing it and kick it. so I would create mutliple sub-task instead of as one giant running task.
2. Not necessary since longrunningtask is the task I need it to be run as celery task, no need its parent to be inside celery task.

Can someone please help me out of this dilemma? It's super frustrating and has been blocking me for a while.

Any suggestion or idea of this use case is also superhelpful!

Comment: - First understand the concept of celery-beats. It's used to schedule
   the periodict task.It is used to trigger normal tasks. Suppose you
   need to delete something from db at 12:00 AM everyday. You can
   celery-beats for it. It doesn't need to be called via another
   method/function. If your tasks depends on parameter than run as
   celery task not beat-scheduling. In your **calling.py** you're not
   calling a celery task, to know how to call a celery task please
   follow this [calling tasks][1]. 
   
   
     [1]: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/calling.html

Comment: One more thing did you put your periodic task code on celery.py?

Comment: @Prantachakraborty, Thanks for the replying, I think my calling part should be right, I missed add the .delay in the post, but I did using delay() to call the acutal tasks . 
I do not recall you need to put periodical task into celery.py. I assume it can be trigger by a view or something else. Do I have to do that?

Comment: I also tried call the perodical task inside the celery.py, still not working.  Since I am caliing a function that is just a normal function but calling a task. It is not recognize it by celery ...